# Proxy database not switching

Tags: spring, spring-batch

- Spring framework 4.1.4
- Spring batch 3.0.2
- Tomcat 7

Morning,

I have successfully used a configuration based on [Marten Deinum's Post](https://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/)
to dynamically connect (or create and connect) to dbs only known at run time.

The problem I am having is the process now intermittently fails to switch between dbs. The first always works but putting in logging code shows the first properly being created and then the second or third not firing `dataSource == null` section in the `MdyDataSourceFactory` - it appears if the process thinks it is the same db and so doesn't change but at some point it triggers and connects to a subsequent db!

Running a simple JUnit test switching between dbs works fine (code correctly fires and dbs switch and select statement returns different id results as expected).

It is being called within a Batch Job step tasklet. The process grabs a count of resultSets (summary table) and connects to the db. For each resultSet it calls the db registry and if exists - returns existing or creates a new one and returns.

My dynamic db xml is:

```
<bean id="mdyDSRegistry" class="com.k12knowledge.db.MdyDataSourceFactory" />

<bean id="mdyDSTargetSource" class="com.k12knowledge.db.ContextSwappableMdyTargetSource">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Class">
        <value>javax.sql.DataSource</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="targetRegistry" ref="mdyDSRegistry"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="proxyMdyDataSource" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces">
        <list>
            <value>javax.sql.DataSource</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="targetSource">
        <ref bean="mdyDSTargetSource" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

The MdyDataSourceFactory is:

```
public class MdyDataSourceFactory implements TargetRegistry {

private ConcurrentMap<String, DataSource> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, DataSource>();

@Override
public DataSource getTarget(String context) {
    IClientDs client = MdyContextHolder.getClientDs();

    Assert.notNull(client, "Client was not set.");
    String key = client.getUrl();
    DataSource dataSource = map.get(key);

    if (dataSource == null) {
        System.out.println("dataSource == null - creating new");
        dataSource = getDataSource(client);
        dataSource = map.putIfAbsent(key, dataSource);
        if (dataSource == null) {
            // put success
            dataSource = map.get(key);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("client key: " + key);
    return dataSource;
}

private DataSource getDataSource(IClientDs client) {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(client.getDriver());
    dataSource.setUrl(client.getUrl());
    dataSource.setUsername(client.getUsername());
    dataSource.setPassword(client.getPassword());
    dataSource.setValidationQuery("/* ping */");
    dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
    dataSource.setMaxIdle(5);
    dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
    dataSource.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    dataSource.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(20);
    dataSource.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(34000);
    dataSource.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(55000);
    try {
        System.out.println("dataSource " + client.getUrl() + " closed ? " + dataSource.getConnection().isClosed());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataSource;
}
```

}

At one point I thought there was an issue with the key I used (some databases are only different in name by 1 letter). I then tried adding an UUID to the front of the key to see if that was the issue - no change.

Really puzzled as to why it is not working... Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Thank you for looking.

ContextHolder

```
public abstract class ContextHolder {
private static final ThreadLocal<IClientDs> holder = new ThreadLocal<IClientDs>();

public static void setClientDs(IClientDs context) {
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContextHolder.class).debug("context set '{}'", context);
    holder.set(context);
}

public static IClientDs getClientDs() {
    return (IClientDs) holder.get();
}
```

}

Comment: What is your own context holder doing and do you really want or need to do that with a `ThreadLocal`, why not a normal singleton that is injected? Is your job multithreaded or single threaded? Another thing is that you are leaking connections from your `DataSource`, you do a `getConnection` but never close it, hence a single connection is leaked. You are using a `ThreadLocal` make sure that you clean that when you are done processing else you might leak information from one execution to another (which can be especially when reusing threads).

Comment: @m-deinum (included `ContextHolder`) Frankly I just followed your post - about the ThreadLocal. The job was multi threaded and I have stripped it down to single threaded trying to resolve this. Hmm - am not cleaning up my `ThreadLocal` and have seen leakage. Not clear on how to implement the singleton suggestion - dbs aren't known (i.e. not in config file) until runtime. If I can avoid ThreadLocal - great.

Comment: a `ThreadLocal` is, as the name suggests, specific for the current thread. Basically it is just a `Map<Thread, YourObject>` wrapper. The current thread functions as a key. So you should always clean up after yourself. Instead you might want to use a singleton which holds all the `IClientDs` in a `volatile` based property. Then in your factory you can do the lookup based on the passed in `context`.

Comment: @m-deinum - thanks for the insights and suggestions.